Training model in loop (new model in each iteration), training time increases after nearly 600 iterations of loop
I am training a LSTM model and validating it using "leave one out" cross validation. I have 11520 samples, so I have to train a new model 11520 times. I am using loop for each split of data given by 'LeaveOneOut" function of scikit learn, inside that loop I am initializing a new model, train it, predict test set and then using "keras.backend.clear_session()" to clear old model, after that using "tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()" to reset graph, then using "gc.collect()" to collect grabage. Initially models are trained in nearly 6-7 seconds but after training 600 models training time increases to 25-50 seconds. Here is my code:
def get_model(channels):

    model2 = keras.models.Sequential()
    model2.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=False))
    model2.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model2  

def leaveOneOutCVLSTM(X, y, epochs, batch_size, validation_split):

    X_shuffle, y_shuffle = shuffle(X, y, random_state=42)
    cv = LeaveOneOut()
    # enumerate splits
    y_true, y_pred = list(), list()
    i = 1
    for train_ix, test_ix in cv.split(X_shuffle):
        # split data
        X_train, X_test = X_shuffle[train_ix, :], X_shuffle[test_ix, :]
        
        scalers = {}
        X_train_scaled = np.random.rand(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])
        X_test_scaled = np.random.rand(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], X_test.shape[2])
        for j in range(X_train.shape[2]):
            scalers[j] = StandardScaler()
            X_train_scaled[:, :, j] = scalers[j].fit_transform(X_train[:, :, j])
        for j in range(X_test.shape[2]):
            X_test_scaled[:, :, j] = scalers[j].transform(X_test[:, :, j])
        
        y_train, y_test = y_shuffle[train_ix], y_shuffle[test_ix]
        # fit model
        new_model = get_model(X_train_scaled.shape[1])
        st = time()
        if(i <= 5):
            new_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split)
        else:
            new_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=validation_split, verbose=False)
        
        # evaluate model
        y_hat = new_model.predict(X_test_scaled, verbose=False)
        
        ed = time()
        dr = ed-st
        print(i," ",dr)
        # store
        y_true.append(y_test[0])
        y_pred.append(y_hat[0])
        i+=1
        keras.backend.clear_session()
        tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
        gc.collect()

    return y_true, y_pred

X_batch = X.reshape(11520, 1, 156)

y_true, y_pred = leaveOneOutCVLSTM(X_batch, Y, 10, 32, 0.2)

And here is the training time I have printed from 1st iteration to 16th iteration
1   8.427346229553223
2   7.397351503372192
3   7.472941875457764
4   7.418887615203857
5   7.5288026332855225
6   6.432919502258301
7   6.417744398117065
8   6.312522649765015
9   6.350329160690308
10   6.340737342834473
11   6.3199241161346436
12   6.310317039489746
13   6.3174097537994385
14   6.346491813659668
15   6.2766053676605225
16   6.296995401382446

and for 600th iteration to 616th iteration
600   26.77048420906067
601   20.864712238311768
602   20.118656873703003
603   23.869750022888184
604   23.6923668384552
605   26.10648512840271
606   23.909359216690063
607   36.399033069610596
608   22.179851055145264
609   16.407938718795776
610   30.585895776748657
611   23.5596022605896
612   25.86080241203308
613   44.86601257324219
614   23.27703547477722
615   24.88290023803711
616   19.156887531280518

I have used keras.backend.clear_session(), tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph(), gc.collect() to clear overhead but still training time increases. So I want to know

Why training time increases after 600 iterations of loop?
What should I do so that training time remains 6-7seconds?


On kaggle I got suggestion that there is some memory leaks is happening, I should use custom training loop and TensorFlow Dataset API for data loading. I did both of this but still after 600 iterations training time increases to 25-50 seconds and after 700 iterations, it crosses 100 seconds. I used @tf.function for optimizing custom training loop as suggested by https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch
